# Uninitialized constant NSJSONSerialization

Tags: macruby, rubymotion, nsjsonserialization

How can I get NSJSONSerialization to be recognized in macruby?

```
framework 'foundation'

puts NSXMLDocument
#=> NSXMLDocument

puts NSJSONSerialization
#=> /Users/home/Desktop/Dropbox/script.rb:3:in `<main>': 
    uninitialized constant NSJSONSerialization (NameError)
```

also

```
$ macruby -v
MacRuby 0.12 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I feel like a dunce, this fails because I was running on Snow Leopard. NSJSONSerialization isn't supported until 10.7.

I'll leave this question up for anyone else who stubbles across the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> framework 'foundation'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts NSJSONSerialization
NSJSONSerialization
=> nil

irb(main):014:0> NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit'], options:0, error:nil).to_str
=> "[\"dog\",\"cat\",\"rabbit\"]"

$ macruby -v
MacRuby 0.13 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]
```

Maybe it's fixed in later builds. This actually is not specific to RubyMotion, but `NSJSONSerialization` is something of broad enough interest it's worth keeping the question tagged as such.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, turns out the NSJSONSerialization isn't support until 10.7 (I was running on Snow Leopard at the time of posting).